# RuntimeError when reading .wav in loop

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, deep-learning, librosa

First, I am a complete novice in deep learning and am trying out this code [Bird Species Classification](https://towardsdatascience.com/cnns-for-audio-classification-6244954665ab) by Papia Nandi.

When calling out the .wav file, an error like this appears:

```
RuntimeError: Error opening 'PE (170).wav': System error.
```

and

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PE (170).wav'
```

There have been similar problems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56755596/runtimeerror-when-reading-wav-file), [this](https://github.com/bastibe/python-soundfile/issues/227) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68692464/runtimeerror-error-opening-system-error-when-reading-wav-file). The difference is theirs is calling the file one at a time while mine is in a for-loop. The error just happens in this for-loop execution whilst calling out the file alone before is [working properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOPBM.jpg) (which proves that the desired file i.e. PE (170) is indeed in the directory).

Below is the loop part and the full error message is this -> https://pastebin.com/AbES3Kcp

```
def get_features(df_in):   
    features=[]     
    labels = [] #empty array to store labels     
    #For each species, determine how many augmentations are needed
    df_in=df_in.reset_index()     
    for i in df_in.bird_id.unique():
           print('bird_id:',i)    
           #all the file indices with the same bird_id     
           filelist = df_in.loc[df_in.bird_id == i].index         
    for j in range(0,len(filelist)):      
            filename = df_in.iloc[filelist[j]].file_name
            print("full path: " + os.path.abspath(filename))
            #define the beginning time of the signal          
            tstart = df_in.iloc[filelist[j]].t_min             
            tend = df_in.iloc[filelist[j]].t_max #end of signal
            file_name = df_in.iloc[filelist[j]].file_name
            bird_id = i
            songtype_id = df_in.iloc[filelist[j]].songtype_id   
            #Load the file
            signal, sr = librosa.load(filename,sr=28000)  
            #cut the file to signal start and end  
            signal_cut=signal[int(round(tstart*sr)):int(round(tend*sr))]  
            #generate features & output numpy array          
            data = generate_features(signal) 
            features.append(data[np.newaxis,...])    
            labels.append(bird_id)     
            output=np.concatenate(features,axis=0)     
            return(np.array(output), labels)
            #use get_features to calculate and store the features
            test_features, test_labels = get_features(pd.concat([X_test,y_test],axis=1))
            train_features, train_labels = get_features_noOS(pd.concat([X_train,y_train],axis=1))
```

This is my whole code. https://pastebin.com/0ucd5QRy

Comment: is it possible that the brackets in file name caused the error?

Comment: Removed them and renamed all the data into a PE_170 format. Instead, the error still persists (but with a new file: BH_080).

Comment: when it says no such file, often you can try use absolute path, your code seems using relative path.

Comment: Yes, thanks, got it. I should have used an absolute path instead of "filename" alone here. `signal, sr = librosa.load(filename,sr=28000)`